# Using List[Char].head in Scala

Tags: scala

New to Scala here. Trying to check with a function if the first character of a list matches.

```
def checkFistChar(chars: List[Char]): Boolean =
  if (chars.head == "3") true
  else false
```

In the line of the condition i get `Comparing unrelated types` and

`checkFistChar("3 is larger than 2".toList)` returns false

Comment: You got "Comparing unrelated types", That's the compiler being very clear about what the problem is (as the answers then explain). I don't know what IDE you use, but you should probably learn how to use it to tell what type something is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value `"3"` is a `String` because you are using double quotes, not a `Char`.  You need to use single quotes instead.  Also, you don't need the if/else:

```
def checkFirstChar(chars : List[Char]) = chars.head == '3'
```

One other problem with your function is that calling `head` on an empty list would throw an exception.  In general you should only use `headOption` which returns an `Option`:

```
//empty list returns false
def safeCheckFirstChar(chars : List[Char]) : Boolean = 
  chars
    .headOption
    .map(_ == '3')
    .getOrElse(false)
```

Which is equivalent to Tzach's & Chris' suggestions in the comments as well as pattern matching:

```
def safeCheckFirstChar2(chars : List[Char]) = 
  chars
    .headOption
    .exists(_ == '3')

def safeCheckFirstChar3(chars : List[Char]) =
  chars.headOption == Some('3')

def safeCheckFirstChar4(chars : List[Char]) = chars.headOption match {
  case Some('3') => true
  case _ => false
}
```

Comment: `.map(_ == '3').getOrElse(false)` can be shortened to `.exists(_ == '3')`

Comment: I was thinking to deal with the empty List with `chars.isEmpty`. I also see that you check '3' as a string. How does your implementation translates string into Char?

Comment: Oh got it, it was the double quotes thing. Thanks!

Comment: @mosmic Why go through the extra effort if `isEmpty`?  The functional + monadic style of doing these checks is usually much easier to maintain and debug than a more imperative style.  Happy hacking...

Comment: @RamonJRomeroyVigil because I'm still new in the "functional" way. Making the first steps here. Appreciating the insight!

Comment: @mosmic I highly recommend the neophyte's guide to scala, it is a good introductory discussion on these topics: http://danielwestheide.com/scala/neophytes.html

Comment: Other options: `chars.headOption.contains('3')`, `chars.headOption == Some('3')`

Comment: If you're going to use pattern matching, just match on the list directly instead of using `headOption`.

Answer (score 3):

You can pattern match on `chars` list directly:

```
def checkFistChar(chars: List[Char]): Boolean =
  chars match {
    case '3' :: _ => true
    case _ => false
  }
```

You can generalise `checkFistChar` even further:

```
def checkFistChar(ch: Char, chars: List[Char]): Boolean =
  chars match {
    case `ch` :: _ => true
    case _ => false
  }
```

This implementation will check that provided `ch` is head of `chars`.

```
checkFistChar('3', Nil) should be(false)
checkFistChar('3', List('3')) should be(true)
checkFistChar('3', List('4')) should be(false)
checkFistChar('3', List('3', '4')) should be(true)
```